# How can I return a variable at last call of recursive function?

Tags: php, function, recursion

I have a recursive function. How can I return a value from this recursive function at the last call?

```
public function deneme($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = 0, $str = '') {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->where('parent_id = ' . $parent_id);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $str .= '<ul>';
        foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {
            if ($parent_id == 0) {
                $str .= '<li class="active">';
            } else {
                $str .= '<li>';
            }
            $str .= '<a href="index.html">' . $row['name'] . '</a> </li> '; 
            $sub_mark++;
            $this->deneme($row['id'], $sub_mark, $str);
        }
        $str .= '</ul>';
    }
}
```

I want to return the `str` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though you need a couple of changes, first to return the built up string from the routine at the end...

```
        }
        $str .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $str;
}
```

The second is where you call the routine recursively, you need to set the the return value to the string you are generating...

```
$str = $this->deneme($row['id'], $sub_mark, $str);
```

Comment: It was going fine but it had go too much, to being limitless loop. I need to stop this at the very last :/

Comment: I think I was adding the string to itself.  I've changed the last line of the code to be `=` instead of `.=` (remove the dot).

Comment: How a monster you are!!! Are you crazy?? You do not know which data model do i use? What I want to do exactly! Also, you could be never faced with this problem forever! How can you see the problem in the code that easily? Thanks man, you are awesome!

Comment: You made me live 5 more years now, thanks up buddy! Seriously!